# PHP shopping cart session not updating after custom session handler incorporated into site

Tags: php, session, cart

i am putting together a basic site with a basic shopping cart, we plan to store sensitive information in the sessions in the future so getting this sorted now is a smart choice.

Everything works fine without the custom session handler, for some context the session handling code is below:

```
function decrypt($edata, $password) {
$data = base64_decode($edata);
$salt = substr($data, 0, 16);
$ct = substr($data, 16);

$rounds = 3; // depends on key length
$data00 = $password.$salt;
$hash = array();
$hash[0] = hash('sha256', $data00, true);
$result = $hash[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < $rounds; $i++) {
    $hash[$i] = hash('sha256', $hash[$i - 1].$data00, true);
    $result .= $hash[$i];
 }
    $key = substr($result, 0, 32);
    $iv  = substr($result, 32,16);

    return openssl_decrypt($ct, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, true, $iv); 

   } 

   function encrypt($data, $password) {

// Set a random salt
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$salted = '';
$dx = '';
// Salt the key(32) and iv(16) = 48
while (strlen($salted) < 48) {
  $dx = hash('sha256', $dx.$password.$salt, true);
  $salted .= $dx;
}

$key = substr($salted, 0, 32);
$iv  = substr($salted, 32,16);

$encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, true, $iv);
return base64_encode($salt . $encrypted_data);

 }

 class SecureSessionHandler extends SessionHandler {
 
protected $name, $cookie;
private  $key;

public function __construct($key, $name = 'MY_SESSION', $cookie = [])
       { 
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->cookie = $cookie;
    $this->cookie += [
        'lifetime' => 0,
        'path'     => ini_get('session.cookie_path'),
        'domain'   => ini_get('session.cookie_domain'),
        'secure'   => isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']),
        'httponly' => true
    ];
     $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256- 
     cbc'));
    $this->setup();
}
private function setup()
{
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    session_name($this->name);
    session_set_cookie_params(
        $this->cookie['lifetime'],
        $this->cookie['path'],
        $this->cookie['domain'],
        $this->cookie['secure'],
        $this->cookie['httponly']
    );

}

public function start()
{
    if (session_id() === '') {
        if (session_start()) {
            return mt_rand(45, 99) === 55 ? $this->refresh() : true; // 1/5
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function forget()
{
    if (session_id() === '') {
        return false;
    }
    $_SESSION = [];
    setcookie(
        $this->name,
        '',
        time() - 42000,
        $this->cookie['path'],
        $this->cookie['domain'],
        $this->cookie['secure'],
        $this->cookie['httponly']
    );
    return session_destroy();
}

public function refresh()
{
    return session_regenerate_id(false);
}

 public function write($id, $data)
{
     $data = encrypt($data, $this->key);
    return parent::write($id, $data);
    
}

public function read($id)
{
     $data = parent::read($id);

    if (!$data) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return decrypt($data, $this->key);
    }
}

public function isExpired($ttl = 30)
{
    $last = isset($_SESSION['_last_activity'])
        ? $_SESSION['_last_activity']
        : false;
    if ($last !== false && time() - $last > $ttl * 60) {
        return true;
    }
    $_SESSION['_last_activity'] = time();
    return false;
}

public function isFingerprint()
{
    $hash = md5(
        $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] .
        (ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long('255.255.0.0'))
    );
    if (isset($_SESSION['_fingerprint'])) {
        return $_SESSION['_fingerprint'] === $hash;
    }
    $_SESSION['_fingerprint'] = $hash;
    return true;
}

public function isValid()
{
    return ! $this->isExpired() && $this->isFingerprint();
}
public function get($name)
{
    $parsed = explode('.', $name);
    $result = $_SESSION;
    while ($parsed) {
        $next = array_shift($parsed);
        if (isset($result[$next])) {
            $result = $result[$next];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
public function put($name, $value)
{
    $parsed = explode('.', $name);
    $session =& $_SESSION;
    while (count($parsed) > 1) {
        $next = array_shift($parsed);
        if ( ! isset($session[$next]) || ! is_array($session[$next])) {
            $session[$next] = [];
        }
        $session =& $session[$next];
    }
    $session[array_shift($parsed)] = $value;
    }
    }

    $key = file_get_contents('./key.pem', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
     $session = new SecureSessionHandler($key);

    ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
    session_set_save_handler($session, true);
    session_save_path(__DIR__ . '/sessions');

   $session->start('cheese');
   if ( ! $session->isValid(5)) {
   $session->destroy('cheese');
    }
```

There is the full session handler and encryption/decryption method, everything works fine overall but the problem is when going through my shopping cart code and changing all the $_SESSION variables into the $session->get objects, i managed to replace every $_SESSION then the last one i need to change throws a fatal error:

changing " $_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents;"
to  "$session->get('cart_contents') = $this->cart_contents;"

results in:

Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\teck\Cart.php on line 375

The rest of the important code is mentioned below, i made sure nothing was left out, its better to have a long post with all details than getting flamed for a small post with a question missing all details lol.

The page that you can adjust the quantity on is viewcart.php, the code thats important from this page is below:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo 
 $item["qty"]; ?>" onchange="updateCartItem(this, '<?php echo 
 $item["rowid"]; ?>')">
```

and the script on the same page (viewcart.php) that throws the alert is below:

```
  <script>
  function updateCartItem(obj,id){
    $.get("cartAction.php", {action:"updateCartItem", id:id, qty:obj.value}, 
  function(data){
        if(data == 'ok'){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            alert('Cart update failed, please try again.');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Now finally cartaction.php, the code for the action "updatecartitem" is below:

```
 }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'updateCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['id']))
 {
    $itemData = array(
        'rowid' => $_REQUEST['id'],
        'qty' => $_REQUEST['qty']
    );
   $updateItem = $cart->update($itemData);
    echo $updateItem?'ok':'err';die;
    
}
```

The update function thats in cart.php:

```
  public function update($item = array()){
    if (!is_array($item) OR count($item) === 0){
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        if (!isset($item['rowid'], $this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']])){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            // prep the quantity
            if(isset($item['qty'])){
                $item['qty'] = filter_var($item['qty'], 
      FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
                // remove the item from the cart, if quantity is zero
                if ($item['qty'] == 0){
                    unset($this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']]);
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            
            // find updatable keys
            $keys = array_intersect(array_keys($this-
       >cart_contents[$item['rowid']]), array_keys($item));
            // prep the price
            if(isset($item['price'])){
                $item['price'] = filter_var($item['price'], 
    FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
            }
            // product id & name shouldn't be changed
            foreach(array_diff($keys, array('id', 'name')) as $key){
                $this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']][$key] = $item[$key];
            }
            // save cart data
            $this->save_cart();


            return TRUE;
        }
    }
  }
```

And last but not least the save_cart function in cart.php also:

```
  protected function save_cart(){
    $this->cart_contents['total_items'] = $this->cart_contents['cart_total'] 
    = 0;
    foreach ($this->cart_contents as $key => $val){
        // make sure the array contains the proper indexes
        if(!is_array($val) OR !isset($val['price'], $val['qty'])){
            continue;
        }
 
        $this->cart_contents['cart_total'] += ($val['price'] * $val['qty']);
        $this->cart_contents['total_items'] += $val['qty'];
        $this->cart_contents[$key]['subtotal'] = ($this->cart_contents[$key]
        ['price'] * $this->cart_contents[$key]['qty']);
    }
    global $key;
    global $session;
    
    // if cart empty, delete it from the session
    if(count($this->cart_contents) <= 2){
        $session->forget();
        return FALSE;
    }else{



        // original code below
     $_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents;
     




      // code below is what i think will clear everything up but throws the 
      //  error.
        $session->get('cart_contents') = $this->cart_contents;
        return TRUE;




    }
    }
```

The cart code above is in the same file as the session handler,

A bit more of an explanation, with " $_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents;" (the original code),

i press the button +1 to add extra item into cart, the text field increases 1, and the error alert pops up saying "Cart update failed, please try again", i click ok and the alert goes away and nothing happens, the item qty in the text box stays updated but the actual real cart qty doesnt update until i refresh the page or click a link.

With the standard session handler in place this doesnt happen, everything works perfectly.

Is it a must that i change this $_SESSION['cart_contents'] variable to $session->get('cart_contents')?

I should be able to change that script alert to update the cart properly without throwing the alert but will my custom session handler work flawlessly if i leave that one session variable?

Im very sorry for the long post but i wanted to make sure everything is as clear as possible for other people to also understand if they are having similar problems.

The code does seem quite messy from this point of view but if you were to go over the entire site everything would make much more sense.

I have been on php for about 2 months max now trying my best to pick up as much as possible so please bear with me, obviously most of the code is not as clean as it should be, but this is production.

I have spent the past 3-4 days on this session handler, i really dont want to discard it and just go back to the standard _session.

All & any advice is welcome, constructive criticism will be taken lightly!

I really appreciate the time you have taken to go through this, Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Some people don't even explain their question, and then there is this guy

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error at line

```
$session->get('cart_contents') = $this->cart_contents;
```

Here I assume the get function returns a reference. So if you want to store $this->cart_contents to the reference variable then you must use $$.
e.g $temp = $session->get('cart_contents');
and use $$temp = $this->cart_contents;

Or if you want to assign $this->cart_contents to the cart values then you must use

```
$this->cart_contents = $session->get('cart_contents');
```

You cant just use get method and assign a value to it.

Comment: I already tried "$this->cart_contents = $session->get('cart_contents');", the cart contents just wont update with that, using the $$ still doesnt work, the only thing that seems to work is the original "$_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents;", il keep researching the $$ maybe im implementing it wrong, thanks for your input .

Comment: should i even be using the get method? what should i use to replace the "$_SESSION['cart_contents']" from my sessionhandler? the get returns the array of the cart details just like printing "$_SESSION['cart_contents']" does so i thought that must be ok to replace it.

Comment: check for set method in the file where you have set function of $session class. Then you can get an idea about how to set a variable in session.

Comment: Your a dead set legend! I feel so silly, i went over the put function instead of the get before i posted here but i must not have configured it correctly! the correct configuration is: $session->put('cart_contents', $this->cart_contents);     But with the alert coded in it still throws the error but updates after a link is hit or page refreshed, i just took the alert out and it still works fine hopefuly the alert isnt too important, il look a bit further into it.. Anyways thanks for the guidance much appreciated i knew there was a way!

Answer (score 0):

Not much i could really do apart from keep researching, what ive done to get it working is below, but can someone please let me know if this will make my custom sessionhandler not work as intended?

i changed the updateCartItem function so there is no if statement just straight calls the function then reloads the page.

```
 <script>
 function updateCartItem(obj,id){
 $.get("cartAction.php", {action:"updateCartItem", id:id, qty:obj.value}, 
 function(data){
        location.reload();
 });
 }</script>
```

This works fine with the save_cart function as below:

```
protected function save_cart(){
$this->cart_contents['total_items'] = $this->cart_contents['cart_total'] 
= 0;
foreach ($this->cart_contents as $key => $val){
    // make sure the array contains the proper indexes
    if(!is_array($val) OR !isset($val['price'], $val['qty'])){
        continue;
    }

    $this->cart_contents['cart_total'] += ($val['price'] * $val['qty']);
    $this->cart_contents['total_items'] += $val['qty'];
    $this->cart_contents[$key]['subtotal'] = ($this->cart_contents[$key]
    ['price'] * $this->cart_contents[$key]['qty']);
}
global $key;
global $session;

// if cart empty, delete it from the session
if(count($this->cart_contents) <= 2){
    $session->forget();
    return FALSE;
}else{
 $_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents;
    return TRUE;
}
}
```

BUT! Shouldnt the $_SESSION variable be replaced with my custom session handler call? ($session->get('cart_contents') = $this->cart_contents;) Obviously il get the error if i change it :(

Everything seems to work fine with the sessions, but will this create a weak point in my session security? And i should be able to use the if statement in the updateCartItem script! There must be a way to use the customsessionhandler call instead of "$_SESSION['cart_contents']".